# How to connect ArduinoWebSockets to nodejs socket.io server deployed in fly.io?

Tags: socket.io, esp8266, fly

Basically, I have an ESP8266 NodeMcu that connects to a wifi network. An RFID reader is connected and whenever the RFID card is tapped on the reader, an instance of `SocketIoClient` from `ArduinoWebSockets` will send an event on the server. I manage to make it work in Node.js Socket.io server deployed in Heroku, but I cannot connect it to my server deployed to Fly.io.

This is my code in my .ino file.

```
const char *server = "sbca-server.fly.dev";
```

inside the setup

```
webSocket.begin(server, 8080);
```

**I am thinking that the problem here is the port of the server in fly.io.**

because it works in Heroku using port `80` but did not work in fly.io.

```
const char *server = "sbca-server.herokuapp.com";
setup(){
    webSocket.begin(server, 80);
}
```

**What is the correct port to use?**

Comment: what is the question? it looks like you ask why it doesn't work if you connect to  a different port?

Comment: Thanks, I have to clear my question out.
What is the correct port to be used for fly.io server?

Comment: I guess it is configurable, but the default HTTP port is 80

Comment: I've tried all the ports based on fly.io docs, 8080, 80 and 443. All of them did not work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't your question. `fly.toml` contains the port mapping. Maybe post this?

Comment: https://github.com/EricEchemane/sbca-server/blob/main/fly.toml

this is my fly.toml file from the server repo

Comment: But this repo doesn't start any WebSocket servers… How is it supposed to work?